# Fuzzy String Matching With Pandas and FuzzyWuzzy,Data matching: TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I have the data file which looks like this -
[image]

And I have another data file which has all the correct country names. 
[image]

For matching both the files that, I am using below:

```
import pandas as pd


names_array=[]
ratio_array=[]
def match_names(wrong_names,correct_names):
    for row in wrong_names:
        x=process.extractOne(row, correct_names)
        names_array.append(x[0])
        ratio_array.append(x[1])
    return names_array,ratio_array

fields = ['name']
#Wrong country names dataset
df=pd.read_csv("wrong-country-names.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1",sep=';', skipinitialspace=True, usecols= fields )
print(df.dtypes)


wrong_names=df.dropna().values


#Correct country names dataset
choices_df=pd.read_csv("country-names.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1",sep='\t', skipinitialspace=True)
correct_names=choices_df.values

name_match,ratio_match=match_names(wrong_names,correct_names)

df['correct_country_name']=pd.Series(name_match)
df['country_names_ratio']=pd.Series(ratio_match)

df.to_csv("string_matched_country_names.csv")

print(df[['name','correct_country_name','country_names_ratio']].head(10))
```

I get the below error:

```
name    object
dtype: object
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-221-a1fd87d9f661>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Drashti Bhatt/Desktop/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Drashti Bhatt/Desktop')

  File "C:\Users\Drashti Bhatt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Drashti Bhatt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Drashti Bhatt/Desktop/untitled0.py", line 27, in <module>
    name_match,ratio_match=match_names(wrong_names,correct_names)

  File "C:/Users/Drashti Bhatt/Desktop/untitled0.py", line 9, in match_names
    x=process.extractOne(row, correct_names)

  File "C:\Users\Drashti Bhatt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fuzzywuzzy\process.py", line 220, in extractOne
    return max(best_list, key=lambda i: i[1])

  File "C:\Users\Drashti Bhatt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fuzzywuzzy\process.py", line 78, in extractWithoutOrder
    processed_query = processor(query)

  File "C:\Users\Drashti Bhatt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fuzzywuzzy\utils.py", line 95, in full_process
    string_out = StringProcessor.replace_non_letters_non_numbers_with_whitespace(s)

  File "C:\Users\Drashti Bhatt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fuzzywuzzy\string_processing.py", line 26, in replace_non_letters_non_numbers_with_whitespace
    return cls.regex.sub(" ", a_string)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I tried with .decode option, but it did not work out. What I am doing wrong?
Any help on this will be much appreciated! Thanks much!

Comment: how does the country-names looks like?

Comment: Also can you try `pd.read_csv("wrong-country-names.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1", skipinitialspace=True)`.

Comment: This is same as my code with extra sep=';'.

Comment: can you paste country-names.csv file? because i tried with a sample file and importing in the way i had shown, it works fine for me without any error.

Comment: please see the picture in question. I have added the screenshot there. And can you share your code if its working??

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working. you can find the differences. But i am not sure if this is solution that you are looking. And i have tried on sample files which i had created manually. I have removed `fields` from `pd.read_csv`.

(... = same as your code)

```
...
def match_names(wrong_names,correct_names):
    for row in wrong_names:
        print('row=',row)
        ...
    return names_array,ratio_array

fields = ['name']
#Wrong country names dataset
df=pd.read_csv("fuzzy.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1", skipinitialspace=True)
print(df.dtypes)

wrong_names=df.dropna().values
print(wrong_names)

#Correct country names dataset
choices_df=pd.read_csv("country.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1",sep='\t', skipinitialspace=True)
correct_names=choices_df.values
print(correct_names)
...

print(df[['correct_country_name','country_names_ratio']].head(10))
```

Output

```
Country         object
alpha-2         object
alpha-3         object
country-code     int64
iso_3166-2      object
region          object
sub-region      object
region-co        int64
sub-region.1     int64
dtype: object
[[u'elbenie' u'AL' u'ALB' 8 u'ISO 3166-2:AL' u'Europe' u'Southern Europe'
  150 39]
 [u'enforre' u'AD' u'AND' 20 u'ISO 3166-2:AD' u'Europe' u'Southern Europe'
  150 39]
 [u'Belerus' u'AT' u'AUT' 40 u'ISO 3166-2:AT' u'Europe' u'Western Europe'
  150 155]]
[[u'elbenie']
 [u'enforre']
 [u'Belerus']]
('row=', array([u'elbenie', u'AL', u'ALB', 8, u'ISO 3166-2:AL', u'Europe',
       u'Southern Europe', 150, 39], dtype=object))
('row=', array([u'enforre', u'AD', u'AND', 20, u'ISO 3166-2:AD', u'Europe',
       u'Southern Europe', 150, 39], dtype=object))
('row=', array([u'Belerus', u'AT', u'AUT', 40, u'ISO 3166-2:AT', u'Europe',
       u'Western Europe', 150, 155], dtype=object))
  correct_country_name  country_names_ratio
0            [elbenie]                   60
1            [enforre]                   60
2            [Belerus]                   60
```

Comment: I tried your way also. But still getting same error.

Comment: @DrashtiBhatt you can print `type(row)`, `type(correct_name)`, `print(row)`, `print(correct_name)`, just before `process.extractOne(row, correct_names)` and paste the output.